# American English Pronunciation of "o" sound long or short?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, north-american-english

I'm always confused about how to pronounce words with letter *o* in spelling. For example, in the word *boss*, I always pronounce the *o* as short o, when in fact it is long o. *Collar* is short, but I always pronounce it the opposite way.

What's the difference between words like *dog*, *top*, *caught* and *cost*? /ɑ/ or /ɔ/ ?

Are there any rules or law to decide whether to pronounce long o or short o?

Comment: There's some potential for confusion here because English phonetics often use _long_ to describe vowel tenseness (like the O in _hose_) rather than duration (like the O in _boss_).

Comment: The most important thing is that “long” and “short” don’t make much sense, as they are used in different ways by different people. As to which sound you get, it all depends on just which types of mergers or splitters the people you’re talking about talking are part of. Remember that the letter *a* also takes on the value from *thought* in words like *call* for most speakers. There is also something going on in parts of California where even more roundedness is being lost than normal. [See here](http://www.soundcomparisons.com/).

Comment: Related: [What source explains the different pronunciations of “hol” in “alcohol” and “hollow”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303766)

Answer (score 5):

See the [lot-cloth split](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_low_back_vowels#Lot.E2.80.93cloth_split) section of Wikipedia. Here are two excerpts:

> The lengthening and raising generally happened before the fricatives /f/, /θ/ and /s/. In American English the raising was extended to the environment before /ŋ/ and /ɡ/, and in a few words before /k/ as well, giving pronunciations like /lɔŋ/ for long, /dɔɡ/ for dog, and /tʃɔklɨt/ for chocolate.
>
> The sound change is most consistent in the last syllable of a word, and much less so elsewhere. Some words that entered the language later, especially when used more in writing than speech, are exempt from the lengthening, e.g. joss and Goth with the short vowel.

Translating from IPA for those people who don't know it, the vowel is generally long before the sounds 'f', 's', 'th', 'g', 'ng', 'nk', especially in one-syllable words. There are exceptions both ways. For example, it's usually short in *cog* and long in *chocolate*. I don't believe there's any way to figure out which words are the exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. And words like top, dog, caught, cost, are they pronounced as  /ɑ/ or /ɔ/ if disregard long or short?

Comment: Unless it's a very unusual dialect, all long 'o's are pronounced with /ɔ/ and all short ones with /ɑ/. The original British short 'o' only split into two sounds in American.

Comment: Actually, let me make an addendum to my last comment. All long 'o's will be pronounced the same, and all short 'o's will be pronounced the same. In dialects with the [Northern Cities Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Cities_Vowel_Shift), these aren't exactly the IPA vowels /ɔ/ and /ɑ/.

Comment: I'm curious; how do you pronounce the letter "o"? Would you be willing to visit [here](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/english/frameset.html), select vowels/monopthongs/back, and hear /o/, and tell me if that is the long o sound?

Comment: What the OP is asking about (from his examples of *dog, top, caught* and *cost*) is the difference between the British short o sounds /ɒ/ which in American have become /ɔ/, as in *dog*, *moth*, *caught*, *cost*, *coffee* and *chocolate* (called "long o" in the question), and those British short o sounds which in American have become /ɑ/, as in *cog*, *cot*, *cop* (called "short o" in the question). The /o/ on that website is **not** the "long o" sound the OP is talking about; he's taking about /ɔ/.

Comment: And the website you refer me to is very confusing, as it implies that *jaw* (listed under /ɔ/) and *raw* (listed under /ɑ/) do not rhyme. I don't pronounce *raw* (/rɔ/) and *rah* (/rɑ/) as homonyms. And I rhyme *jaw* and *raw*.

Comment: Peter you understand quite well my question. i'm deeply confused about the different ways of pronouncing "o" by Americans and the British. I can understand most of the words with long "o" are like /ɔ:/(as used in IPA), and with short are /ɑ/.

Comment: Amd "o" is the most difficult to pronounce When I change from British English to  American English.

Answer (score -1):

I pronounce "boss" and "collar" the same, just as I say "father".  I'm from the US.

Comment: dog, boss, collar, caught, and cost all use the same sound to my ear.

Comment: There's a difference in vowel duration, which is usually called _length_ in phonetics. Unfortunately, English language teachers typically use _length_ to describe a completely different quality.